# How to add styles based on whether top element is empty

Tags: css

How do you change styles of another element based on whether the first element is empty.

```
<ul></ul>
<ul>
<li>....</li>
<li>....</li>
<li>....</li>
</ul>
```

In the above code, I want to give a style for the second ul { color:red } (to be more exact the ul that follows) ONLY if the first ul is empty.

Is there a pure CSS solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, but only if the element in question is completely empty- yes, not even a whitespace.

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/uTJ4N/

```
ul:empty + ul
{
    color: red;
}
```

To be more accurate, this is the selector you need for the first empty `<ul>` of the body and the exact following `<ul>`:

```
body > ul:first-of-type:empty + ul
{
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/uTJ4N/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ul > li {
   color: red;
}
```

Its selects the `ul` which has a `li` as child element. And those can be colored red then.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/KfaQv/1/

```
ul:not(:empty) {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think a pure css solution is the way to go, but you can use a pre-processor as they allow you to pass conditional statements.